# Redirecting to external page from django class based view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to redirect users based on the referer in the request header. Basically, if the referer is say https://www.google.com, I would like to send them to a page, not on my website. Otherwise, continue processing as usual.

Here is what I have so far

```
class ArticleAccess(TemplateView, SomeMixin):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    template_name = 'template.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ArticleAccess, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(ArticleAccess, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        item = get_object_or_404(ClientItem.objects.using(self.get_site().name), id=kwargs['article_id'])

        if self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == 'https://www.google.com/':
            return redirect(item.item_url)

        context['id'] = item.id
        context['name'] = item.name
        context['html'] = item.description
        context['item_url'] = item.item_url

        return context
```

This just stays on the same page instead of redirecting. I have also tried HttpResponseRedirect, but to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alecxe is correct.. you'd have to redirect from a method that is expected to return an `HttpResponse`.

`get_context_data` is not expected to return an `HttpResponse` and isn't ever returned by the `view`. It's always used to get a data dict to populate say a template. No matter what you return from this method, it will never override the response.

Therefore wherever you write this override, it needs to be in a place that is expected to return a response, such as `get`, `post`, `dispatch`.

The problem now is to determine how to get your object outside of the `get_context_data` method.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you think it would make sense for me to write a wrapper function that decides whether to redirect or call the view?

Comment: @JawwadZakaria that's not a bad idea, but this seems very specific to the article view. I personally err on the side of being as straight forward as possible. Especially when the logic is quite simple.

Comment: Ok so I followed your advice and added the redirect to the dispatch method using an HttpResponseRedirect. However, that does not do anything. It returns a 200 and I'm not redirected to the necessary page. Is there some documentation you would recommend I go over to see what I might be missing?

Comment: @JawwadZakaria at this point the documentation will be "Python debugging". Your IF statement must not be firing, because if a method called `dispatch` on a django class based view returns anything but the default, you will know! Start to debug why your response isn't being returned. Check if statement conditions. Use prints, logs, pdb to determine why your override isn't triggering.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, I recommend you to start by just using a plain redirect('some_view') without conditions on your dispatch method so you can check if redirection is hit as expected and only then, go for conditions and anything else. @Yuji-tomita-tomita is just right! :) Django-pdb and ipdb are very nice tools.